# Verilog questions

Tags: output, verilog, assign, digital, digital-logic

I don't know what is wrong with my code, probably a lot of things.  right now, I cannot figure out how to assign register values to my En outputs.  I am required to use Verilog code for a digital circuits course right now.  I am a little fed up with it.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    /
// Company: 
// Engineer: 
// 
// Create Date:    13:57:18 03/15/2016 
// Design Name: 
// Module Name:    Moving7Seg 
// Project Name: 
// Target Devices: 
// Tool versions: 
// Description: 
//
// Dependencies: 
//
// Revision: 
// Revision 0.01 - File Created
// Additional Comments: 
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module Moving7Seg( B, C, Rst, ClkIn, D6, D5, D4, D3, D2, D1, D0, En3, En2, En1, En0 );

input B, C, Rst, ClkIn;
output D6, D5, D4, D3, D2, D1, D0, En3, En2, En1, En0;

//wire D6, D5, D4, D3, D2, D1, D0, En3, En2, En1, En0;

reg ClkOut = 0;
reg bLast = 0;
reg cLast = 0;
//reg rstLast = 0;

reg [3:0]count = 0;
reg [3:0]enable = 4'b0001;


clockdivider getClk(ClkIn, ClkOut);
seg7 convert(count[3], count[2], count[1], count[0], D6, D5, D4, D3, D2, D1, D0);



always @(posedge ClkOut) begin
    if(Rst == 1) begin
        count = 0;
        enable = 4'b0001;
    end

    if(B != bLast && B == 0) begin
        case(enable)
        4'b0001: enable = 4'b0010;
        4'b0010: enable = 4'b0100;
        4'b0100: enable = 4'b1000;
        default: enable = 4'b0001;
        endcase
    end

    if(C != cLast && C == 0) begin
        count = count + 1;
    end

bLast = B;
cLast = C;
//rstLast = Rst;


end

En3 <= enable[3];
En2 <= enable[2];
En1 <= enable[1];
En0 <= enable[0];
convert;

endmodule
```

Comment: Change `output D6, D5, D4, D3, D2, D1, D0, En3, En2, En1, En0;` to `output D6, D5, D4, D3, D2, D1, D0;` and another line  `output reg En3, En2, En1, En0;`

Comment: All the assignments like `En3 <= enable[3];` should be inside procedural blocks. No need to call a module instance (`convert` in the end). Instances are automatically executed at each time step.

Comment: I did have the assignments like 'En3 <= enable[3];' at the end of the always block, but this still was not recognized."Reference to scalar wire 'En3' is not a legal reg or variable lvalue"

Comment: provide all module/function definition, then its quite simple to solve

Answer (score 1):

1) If those "En" outputs are supposed to reflect the current state of the `enable` signal, then you probably need to "assign" the values like so (and keep them outside the `always` block):

```
    assign En3 = enable[3];
    assign En2 = enable[2];
    assign En1 = enable[1];
    assign En0 = enable[0];
```

2) As mentioned in a comment, remove that extra "convert" line.

3) All of the assignments that are inside the always block should really be non-blocking. That is, use the `<=` assignment operator, not the `=` operator.

4) You probably want an `else` case for the check of `Rst`. That is, all of the updating of enable, count, etc, should only happen if `Rst != 0`.

5) You probably also want to reset `bLast` and `cLast` as well.